# Non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context JFrame

Tags: java, swing, constructor, static, jframe

I have this code:

```
private static void inputGUI() {
    inputFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    inputFrame.setTitle("The INPUT");
    panel.add(printButton);
    printButton.setBounds(135,560,120,30);
    inputFrame.setLayout(null);
    inputFrame.add(panel);
    panel.setBounds(1000,100,366,768-100);

    //ActionListeners!!!    
    printButton.addActionListener(this);
    inputFrame.setSize(1366,768);
    inputFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

I wanted to add an action listener to my JButton named

```
printButton
```

I also have a JFrame

```
inputFrame
```

and this in my Main

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    inputGUI();
}
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
```

How can I do this? It would be great if you guys can help me without using an anonymous inner class.(My teacher hasn't taught us that lesson yet). Thank you!

Comment: We need to see the whole class to diagnose your problem.  Ideally, you'd eliminate unnecessary details from your code first before giving a short example that lets us reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can make your method non-static.

Comment: You can either make printButton and inputFrame static (easier), or convert your static method into a non-static method, initialize an instance of your class, and call your method on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code is causing the problem.

```
 printButton.addActionListener(this);
```

**Reason:**
`inputGUI()` is static as a result of which using `this` keyword which refers to the current object is denied.

**Solution:**
Simply create a new object of the class which handles the click events of `printButton`. Say MainClass is responsible for that. Change your code as following:

```
 printButton.addActionListener(new MainClass());
```

**Alternate Solution:**
Make `inputGUI()` non static. And call it from main method as `new MainClass().inputGUI()`. Rest remains same.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class NewClass {


    public NewClass(){
     //inputGUI();
    }
    public static void method(){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "");
    }
    private static void inputGUI() {
    JFrame inputFrame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton printButton = new JButton();
    inputFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    inputFrame.setTitle("The INPUT");
            panel.add(printButton);
                printButton.setBounds(135,560,120,30);
    inputFrame.setLayout(null);
        inputFrame.add(panel);
    panel.setBounds(1000,100,366,768-100);

    //ActionListeners!!!    
        printButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
              method();
            }
        });
inputFrame.setSize(1366,768);
inputFrame.setVisible(true);
}
    public static void main(String[]args){
     inputGUI();   
    }
}
```

you mean like this?